# Evolution mail - backup readable and searchable

Tags: backup, email, evolution

I'm using Evolution to link to my institute's Exchange Web Server (EWS), the problem is that the storage space of the latter is very limited.

What I am looking for is the following:

**Previously, while still using MS Outlook I could delete content via the webmail client, while the emails remained locally in Outlook. This way all my emails remained easily accessible, even after creating additional space, that is deleting emails, on my online account.**

However, I did not figure out how to achieve the same in Evolution. Since here, when I delete an item though webmail, it directly synchronizes to Evolution also.

I did consider using the option `"Back up Evolution Data"` but I'm afraid this will only attempt the sync again resulting in the loss of emails. The save to mbox option IMHO doesn't facilitate the easy access I am looking for, and furthermore results in the following error when attempting to save the whole inbox: `"Failed to move message cache file"` without any further specification. The very same error is also shown when I try to copy the inbox folder to a folder `"On This Computer"`.

What approach could you advise me, and, if similar to one of the latter approaches I mentioned above; what might solve the error?

(I did try Google and this board but without luck or while using the wrong search terms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I do not consider this option as ideal, so feel free to comment or answer and get the honor of being the accepted answer.* This does however offer me a more convenient solution compared to the options I noted above; which is why I am answering my own question now.

Copying both the Inbox and the Sent items to a dedicated folder inside "On This Computer" allows for easy accessibility and a genuine local copy of the emails. Thus allowing me to have the same accessibility and search-ability with respect to the regular mailbox, even after deleting them from the server.

The reason why this is not ideal is that both mailboxes are not automatically synched, that is it is not trivial until where the emails are in the locally stored folder and until where they are still on the server. In other words this approach still involves manual labor.

Comment: This is good enough to get a snapshot of the emails, e.g. when leaving a company/institution. Thanks for the handy tip!